# Text wrapper using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple text editor for a website which works something like forums, e.g. if the user clicks on font color(**after selecting a particular text**), the selected text should be wrapped around some text something like `[FONT COLOR="some_color"]` sample `text[/FONT]`

I don't wanna use tinymce, because it's mammoth for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) is lightweight, customizable and extensible. I've been using it for a project and I am very happy with it. It requires the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library, though.